# SSAS cube aggregation formula when all dimensions' values are the same

Tags: ssas, cube, drilldown

I defined a cube with some dimensions.
When in the fact table, some rows have the same value for every dimension the cube stores only one aggregate row and applies the SUM function on all numeric measures, but I need to calculate the AVG.

Is it possible to choose the aggregation formula for each measure when rows can have same values on all dimenions?

In addition, related to this, I notice that when I browse my cube and drill down (e.g. with an Excel pivot), I don't see a row for each record in the fact table, but a single row for all records having the same values for all dimensions, with the SUM of all numeric fields.
Is it in some way possible to drill down to the orginal table records?

For better comprehension I created this very simple structure:

Dimension data:
[image]

Fact data:
[image]

Cube structure:
[image]

Cube browse result:
[image]

An Excel pivot grid:
[image]

And the result of the drill down on member [Dimensione 1]:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but I noticed that:

- in multidimensional databases, the data is stored in aggregated way; I didn't find how to choose what type of aggregation (SUM, AVG, etc.) can be applied during processing, but detail data became unreachable unless you return with some key on OLTP
- in tabular databases you still can query detail data, following model relationships

So I reproduced the same model on tabular database and solved this issue.
Hope this will be helpful to someone.